# Drawing reversible rectangle

Tags: c#

I got code from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314945 to draw a reversible/rubber band rectangle. I added code to it so that when i leave the left mouse button a rectangle is also created on the image and then i use that for cropping the image.

This works superb. the only problem is that the rubberband rectangle doesnot start or end from where the mouse is... there is very little diference but still it is quite notable. i use the same co-ords to draw the rectangle afterwards which is drawn exactly where my mouse started and where is ended. help would be appreciated.

Here is the code: (Got issue fixed - adding code that others can benefit from it)
I have made it a control and i use it wherever i need it!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CroppingControl
{
    public partial class CroppingImage : UserControl
    {
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle();
        Boolean bHaveMouse;
        Point ptOriginal = new Point();
        Point ptLast = new Point();
        Image Pic;

        public CroppingImage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MyMouseDown);
            pictureBox1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(MyMouseUp);
            pictureBox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MyMouseMove);
            bHaveMouse = false;
        }


        public Image Image
        {
            set
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = value;
                Pic = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return pictureBox1.Image;
            }
        }

        public void MyMouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Pic;
            // Make a note that we "have the mouse".

            bHaveMouse = true;
            // Store the "starting point" for this rubber-band rectangle.
            ptOriginal.X = e.X;
            ptOriginal.Y = e.Y;
            // Special value lets us know that no previous
            // rectangle needs to be erased.
            ptLast.X = -1;
            ptLast.Y = -1;
        }

        // Convert and normalize the points and draw the reversible frame.
        private void MyDrawReversibleRectangle(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            Point px = p1;
            Point py = p2;

            // Convert the points to screen coordinates.
            p1 = PointToScreen(p1);
            p2 = PointToScreen(p2);
            // Normalize the rectangle.
            if (p1.X < p2.X)
            {
                rc.X = p1.X;
                rc.Width = p2.X - p1.X;
            }
            else
            {
                rc.X = p2.X;
                rc.Width = p1.X - p2.X;
            }
            if (p1.Y < p2.Y)
            {
                rc.Y = p1.Y;
                rc.Height = p2.Y - p1.Y;
            }
            else
            {
                rc.Y = p2.Y;
                rc.Height = p1.Y - p2.Y;
            }
            // Draw the reversible frame.
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rc, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed);

            rc.X = px.X;
            rc.Y = px.Y;

        }
        // Called when the left mouse button is released.
        public void MyMouseUp(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set internal flag to know we no longer "have the mouse".
            bHaveMouse = false;
            // If we have drawn previously, draw again in that spot
            // to remove the lines.
            if (ptLast.X != -1)
            {
                Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
                Graphics graphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
                Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 2);
                pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDot;
                graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rc);

            }
            // Set flags to know that there is no "previous" line to reverse.
            ptLast.X = -1;
            ptLast.Y = -1;
            ptOriginal.X = -1;
            ptOriginal.Y = -1;
        }
        // Called when the mouse is moved.
        public void MyMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            // If we "have the mouse", then we draw our lines.
            if (bHaveMouse)
            {
                // If we have drawn previously, draw again in
                // that spot to remove the lines.
                if (ptLast.X != -1)
                {
                    MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
                }
                // Update last point.
                ptLast = ptCurrent;
                // Draw new lines.
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptCurrent);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code? How did you get the mouse coordinates, how are you using those coords?

Comment: did the example code work without the little difference? If so - please post your code - so one could see where the difference happens.

Answer (score 2):

`ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame` uses screen co-ordinates to draw a rectangle on the screen (i.e. without respect to your application's windows) which is useful when acting upon drag mouse actions as the mouse may move outside of the application window.  If you are using these very same co-ordinates raw to paint in your application, then they will be out as the co-ordinates on the control upon which you are painting are with respect to the control's origin (usually its top-left corner).

To use the screen co-ordinates, you first need to convert them into control co-ordinates using the `PointToClient()` or `RectangleToClient()` methods on the control upon which you are painting, e.g.

```
// panel`s OnPaint
Rectangle screenRectangle = ...
Rectangle clientRectangle = panel.RectangleToClient(screenRectangle);
graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, clientRectangle);
```

Comment: this is the code that i am using

public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle();
        Boolean bHaveMouse;
        Point ptOriginal = new Point();
        Point ptLast = new Point();
        PictureBox pic = null;

        Form1 form;

        public Form2(Form1 form1,PictureBox picturebox)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pic = picturebox;
            pictureBox1.Image = picturebox.Image;
            form = form1;
        }

Comment: i am new to this site... the code is quite lengthy and i cannot paste all of it in the comment box... but i have not changed the code much and the problem is also in its like 20 pixels away from the location where i click...

Comment: First of all i would thank all of you for the help :-) I just checked the code... there is no problem in the code provided in the microsoft link... the problem is in my code... the difference is that provided code is drawing rectangle on the the form and i changed it to draw on the picturebox.

Is there a way that i can paste all of my code here??

Comment: Not in a comment, no, but you can edit your question.  (To format code, just put four spaces at the begginning of every line.)

Comment: @Umar: by the way, if what you are saying is true (about form versus picture box) then you should simply be able to change the code that converts from screen to client coordinates to use the picturebox too, i.e. call RectangleToClient on your PictureBox rather than on the form.

Comment: Code added to question... dramatically issue is fixed when i made it a control... still dont know what was causing the problem. Check the code... im sure it will benefit u guys!