# How to Resize the drawn rectangle image in picture box using C#.net?

Tags: c#, winforms

User need to resize the drawn rectangle image, Image is loaded in picturebox.
My image is loaded in picturebox, Based on some co-ordinates(x,y,width,height) I drawn multiple rectangles in that images. Now i want user to resize each and every image and to save the new resized coordinates. How to do this ?
To draw a rectangle i used  `g.DrawRectangle(pen, m_rectangle)` where g denotes a Graphics.

So, my question is how i can add resize (control) for all the drawn rectangles, so that user can resize the rectangle size by dragging towards different position within that rectangle co-ordinates, and then need to save the new resized co-ordinates.

How i can achieve this using Graphics Class ? Any help ? Please guide me.

Comment: what do you mean *how i can add resize (control) for all the drawn rectangles*? What is your code so far

Comment: Take a good look at the many [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) formats. A few of them will let you copy a part of one image onto another one scaled.

Comment: @valter: I want to resize the drawn rectangle Via UI and update the new coordinates. Code is  m_rectangle = new Rectangle(left, 1404, (right - left), 465);
                    g.DrawString(FieldName, font1, Brushes.Green, m_rectangle); 
                    g.DrawRectangle(highlightBorder, m_rectangle); like this i drawn 12 rectangle. Now for all the 12 rectangles i want the user to resize ..

Comment: Your task is not trivial. You are asking us to write code for your project and this is not the purpose of SO

Comment: Just I am asking the way to do this. How to drag the drawn rectangle for resizing ??

Comment: First you need to change the cursor when you are on the rectangle, and then after mouse_down event redraw the hole image and rectangle in mouse_move event.

Comment: Maybe this will help you [Drawing reversible rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895595/drawing-reversible-rectangle)

Comment: If you want to __do__ anything with the Rectangles you will have to __store__ them: A `List<Rectangle>` would be a good place. If you want to __resize__ parts of the original Image you will need new `Bitmaps` to hold those enlarged parts and you'll have to do the enlarging. You __know how__ to do that because you have followed the link I gave you, right??

Comment: Note: If you have drawn your rectangles __onto__ the PictureBox in the Paint event you are good. If you have drawn them __into__ the PictureBox.Image you have destroyed a few of its pixels.. We'll be better able to help if you show us more code.

Comment: You also need to understand that a `Rectangle` is not a thing like a `Panel`. It can't be drawn or moved or resized by a user. It really is just a structure of four integer numbers. That's all. You can use one together with a `Brush` to make a Graphics paint a few Pixels on a `Bitmap`, but that is all that happens: a few Pixels have changed their colors. There is no rectangle there, except in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: I drawn rectangle in image using pen, g.DrawRectangle(highlightBorder, m_rectangle); here highlightBorder is Pen highlightBorder = new Pen(Color.Red, 2); my image contains more than 5 rectangles using pen. So, i cant use picturebox_mousedown or picturebox_mouseleave event because my picturebox is drawn with multiple rectangle, so i dont know in which rectangle my event is elapsed to calculate the coordinates.